# numpy / python - What is the largest matrix multiplication you have done and how did you do it?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm interested in understanding how you perform your matrix multiplications efficiently when dealing with large matrices.

I'm coming across problems with matrices with the following sizes.

```
T = A * P * B
A: 2601 x 40000
P: 40000 x 40000
B: 40000 x 2601
```

P is a diagonal sparse matrix.
All of them are of dtype `np.longcomplex`.

Thank you

EDIT:

the multiplication I have problems with:

```
A.H1*P*A.H2 # takes forever
# A is a class I've defined, A.H1 and A.H2 are a np.matrix, dtype np.longcomplex
# P is a scipy.sparse.dia_matrix of dtype np.longcomplex
print A.H1.shape
    (2601, 40000)
print A.H2.shape
    (40000, 2601)
print A.H1.flags
    C_CONTIGUOUS : False
    F_CONTIGUOUS : True
    OWNDATA : False
    WRITEABLE : True
    ALIGNED : True
    UPDATEIFCOPY : False
print A.H2.flags
    C_CONTIGUOUS : True
    F_CONTIGUOUS : False
    OWNDATA : True
    WRITEABLE : True
    ALIGNED : True
    UPDATEIFCOPY : False
%timeit A.H1*A.H2[:,0]
    1 loops, best of 3: 922ms per loop
```

Comment: why the votes to close? please let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: What problems have you come across?

Comment: If `P` is diagonal, then only store its diagonal as a column vector (shape `(N,1)`) and compute `P * B`. Or even better, if you can afford to throw away `B`: `B *= P`. Then you only have one matmult to do.

Comment: Another option is to use `einsum`: `np.einsum('ij,j,jk', A, P, B)` assuming `P` is just the diagonal as a 1-d array.

Comment: is there anything inherent about that function that makes it faster?

Answer (score 2):

It's not python, but i've done matrix diagonalisation using [PARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~kristyn/parpack_home.html) with matrices up to 220K dimension.

For dense matrices, i couldn't go above around 100K, as there seems to be an issue with PARPACK's `dsyevd` routine (i think it was that one) when you go above 100K dimension.

Numpy will just use libraries like this though, so i don't see why it wouldn't work. You need a lot of memory though.

The matrices i was looking at ranged from ~1% to 10% dense, and for all of those the dense diagonalisation was much faster, but required more memory.

As far as cpu resources, i've been using machines with up to 1TB of ram, and up to 48 cores. It took around a week to diagonalise the largest matrices, dropping down to a few days for ~120K dimension using an iterative diagonaliser as going for 20K eigen values. Diagonalisation requires many multiplication operations though, so it takes longer.

I don't see why you'd be facing problems for just 40K dimension matrices.

[here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2010/09/15/) is a nice comparison of different, which at the very least you can take away a ballpark upper limit on the speed you might be able to achieve.

I don't have the timings on hand from the runs i did a while back at the moment to know how long a single multiplication should take. A while ago, i looked to find benchmarks for this kinf of stuff too, to try and estimate how long some of my larger jobs would take, and found that most of them really do not go to very high dimension at all.

If you can spare the memory, i'd advise trying out treating the matrices as dense, sometimes it can be faster.

Okay, so here are a few numbers from a run i recently did;

```
20000 Eigenvectors to be computed for
128252 dimensional final Hamiltonian matrix
 ======================================================
  inside subroutine --> 'mkarp' --> begins. 

  1. nstat -->                  20000
  2. nhdim -->                 128252
  3. nelm  -->             1132432736
  4. row_index_array(10)    -->          325
  5. column_index_array(10) -->            1
  6. ham_elem_array(10)     -->  -4.394871986531061E-004
 ===========================================================================
  Inside subroutine: 'arpack_coo_openmp_auto_fortran'. 

  total_time_matrix_vector_products (seconds) -->    621072.255066099     
  total_time_dsaupd_subroutine (seconds) -->    4954412.38241189     
  total_time_dseupd -->    157470.167896000 


 ===========================================================================
 ===========================================================================
  Inside subroutine: 'arpack_coo_openmp_auto_fotran'. 

  _sdrv1 
  ====== 

  size of the matrix is -->                 128252
  the number of ritz values requested is -->                  20000
  the number of arnoldi vectors generated (ncv) is -->        40001
  the portion of the spectrum is --> SA
  the number of converged ritz values is -->        20000
  the number of implicit arnoldi update iterations taken is -->           6
  the number of op*x is -->        86080
  the convergence criterion is -->   1.110223024625157E-016

 ===========================================================================
```

So, i *think* what you can take away from that, is that it performed 86080 matrix multiplications, and took 621072 seconds (about a week) - but that's spread across lots of cores. That's 7.2 seconds per operation - which would seem to agree with the ballpark number you had of 2-3 seconds. I *think* also, that a big part of this kind of thing is simply held back by the memory bandwidth (it's always mentioned in the benchmarks).

Comment: well the problem is mainly around the time it takes. I have no idea what I should expect. For me the "simple" calculation of `A * P * B[:,0]` took 3-4 s which means the entire thing would take a few hours. Is this to be expected. Can I speed it up somehow?

Comment: Anothing thing we could note too though, you have `A * P * B[:,0]` - am i right to assume that's inside a loop and being done many times? You might be able to save my doing the equivalent of factoring out common components.

Comment: Could you give an example of your code which will take too long?

Comment: well I haven't tried to do the A*P*B because it never finished. The A*P*B[:,0] is taking 2-3 seconds... and I have no idea why it takes so long

Comment: I've been trying to get a simple code that demonstrates the problem but when I do np.random.rand implementation it runs much faster... like 100 times :( so trying to see what if anything is special about the problematic implementation

Comment: How did you create the matrix which worked slower? Was it just a native python array of arrays? Or a numpy array?

Comment: I've added some more info. It's a numpy array. It was created using broadcasting rules. at some point it was using arbitrary precision objects stored in an array but I gave up on that and went with `np.longcomplex` to speed things up after a certain point